# Python DFS nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I've written a function which should be able to search a nested dictionary, using DFS, to find a specific value. The recursive element seems to be working fine, however, when the base case should return True, it simply doesn't.

```py
obj = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'i':'j'}]}

def obj_dfs(obj, target):
  
  if type(obj) == dict:
    for key, val in obj.items():
      obj_dfs(key, target)
      obj_dfs(val, target) 
  
  elif type(obj) in (list, tuple):
    for elem in obj:
      obj_dfs(elem, target)
  else:
    if obj == target:
      print(f"{obj} == {target}")
      return True
    else:
      print(f"{obj} != {target}")  
  return False 

obj_dfs(obj, 'j')
```

And the results. As you can see, the standard output "i==i" shows that this element was evaluated correctly but the return True statement isn't functioning as intended. I've verified that if I call `obj_dfs(obj, 'j')`, that experiences the same error.

```
a != j
c != j
d != j
e != j
f != j
b != j
g != j
h != j
i != j
j == j
False
```

Why is this? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Your `return True` is being executed in a subfunction somewhere in your recursion, and the value isn't passed up the chain; it's simply lost. You need the parent function to return True if a child returned True.

Comment: @Zorgoth, makes sense. Any suggestions on how?

Comment: One of the answers below quietly replaced your `type(...) == ...` and `type(...) in (...)` with `isinstance(..., ...)`. The documentation explicitly advises to use `isinstance` rather than `type` in this situation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments point out, you need to return the results of the recursive calls. Since you are just looking for a True/False match, you can pass the recursive calls into [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) which will exit early with `True` if there is a match. The base case can simple be whether `obj == target`.

```
obj = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'i':'j'}]}

def obj_dfs(obj, target):
    if obj == target:
        return True

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return any(obj_dfs(v, target) for v in obj.items())
    
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return any(obj_dfs(l, target) for l in obj)

    return False
                   
obj_dfs(obj, 'i'), obj_dfs(obj, 'j'), obj_dfs(obj, 'd'), obj_dfs(obj, 'x')
# (True, True, True, False)
```

This allows for a three simple blocks. Notice we are checking for a `tuple` as well as a `list` in the last `isinstance`. This allows you to simply pass in the dict `item()`s rather than looping over keys and values independently.

Adding a `print(obj)` as the first line of the function will show the order in which you are traversing the data. For example `obj_dfs(obj, 'j')` will print:

```
{'a': [{'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}], 'b': [{'g': 'h'}, {'i': 'j'}]}
('a', [{'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}])
a
[{'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
{'c': 'd'}
('c', 'd')
c
d
{'e': 'f'}
('e', 'f')
e
f
('b', [{'g': 'h'}, {'i': 'j'}])
b
[{'g': 'h'}, {'i': 'j'}]
{'g': 'h'}
('g', 'h')
g
h
{'i': 'j'}
('i', 'j')
i
j
```

Comment: In the isinstance line with the dict type, the input is a tuple, I wouldn't have expected that to work, but I suppose the tuple is just handled by the tuple/list block thanks to recursion! Very insightful

Answer (score 0):

I made some edits to your code

```
obj = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'i':'j'}]}

def obj_dfs(obj, target):
  if type(obj) == dict:
    for key, val in obj.items():
      if(key==target):
        return val
      else:
        result=obj_dfs(val, target)
        if result!=None: return result
  elif type(obj) in (list, tuple):
    for elem in obj:
      result=obj_dfs(elem, target)
      if result!=None: return result
  else: 
    if obj==target: return True

print(obj_dfs(obj, 'i'))
```

I don't know why you would just return true instead of the value though, so I put it that if its a dictionary key it would return the value, instead it would return true, to show that it is found

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, try this, where we pass return values up the chain and always return `True` if a child returned `True`:

```
obj = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'i':'j'}]}
obj2 = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'g':'j'}]}

def obj_dfs(obj, target):
    if type(obj) == dict:
        for key, val in obj.items():
            keyret = obj_dfs(key, target)
            valueret = obj_dfs(val, target)
        if keyret is True or valueret is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif type(obj) in (list, tuple):
        rets = []
        for elem in obj:
            rets.append(obj_dfs(elem, target))
        if True in rets:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if obj == target:
            print(f"{obj} == {target}")
            return True
        else:
            print(f"{obj} != {target}")
            return False

print(obj_dfs(obj, 'i'))
print(obj_dfs(obj2, 'i'))
```

Comment: `if keyret is True or valueret is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False` is a long and complex way to express `return (keyret or valueret)`

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means decoupling concerns and pushing side effects to the fringe of your program. `obj_dfs` performs a depth-first traversal *and* mixes in search logic. And for purposes of debugging, includes a `print` side effect.

Decomposition results in functions that are easier to write, test, and reuse in various parts of our program. We'll start with a generic `dfs` for traversal -

```py
def dfs(t, path = []):
  if isinstance(t, dict):
    for key, val in t.items():
      yield from dfs(val, [*path, key])
  elif isinstance(t, (list, tuple)):
    for key, val in enumerate(t):
      yield from dfs(val, [*path, key])
  else:
    yield path, t
```

```py
obj = {'a': [{'c':'d'}, {'e':'f'}],
       'b': [{'g':'h'}, {'i':'j'}]}

for path, val in dfs(obj):
  print(path, val) # side effect decided by caller
```

```
['a', 0, 'c'] d
['a', 1, 'e'] f
['b', 0, 'g'] h
['b', 1, 'i'] j
```

The suggested solution and other answers here collapse the semantic difference between *key* and *value*, providing no differentiation on the particular match of `target`. Writing `dfs` as we did above, we can know which part of `obj` matched.

| keys | values |
| --- | --- |
| ['a', 0, 'c'] | d |
| ['a', 1, 'e'] | f |
| ['b', 0, 'g'] | h |
| ['b', 1, 'i'] | j |

`has_value` and `has_key` are easily defined in terms of `dfs` -

```py
def has_value(t, target):
  for path, val in dfs(t):
    if val == target:
      return True
  return False

def has_key(t, target):
  for path, val in dfs(t):
    if target in path:
      return True
  return False
```

```py
print(has_value(obj, "j"))   # True
print(has_key(obj, "j"))     # False

print(has_value(obj, "i"))   # False
print(has_key(obj, "i"))     # True
```